# What do the Viltrumites do with their conquered planets?

Tags: comics, invincible

I've watched the 1st and 2nd seasons of *Invincible*, and I've concluded that the show is never going to explain *why* Viltrum wants to conquer Earth or any other planet, nor will the show ever explain what the Viltrum Empire stands to gain after conquering any planet.

**What exactly does the Viltrum Empire want to do with the Earth? Are they planning to exploit its resources in some way?**